# How to create models directly for OneToOne Relationships in Django

Tags: django, django-models

As far as I read, I can create Items in the Django Shell and in the admin panel after some configuration.
But what I want is a "Subitem" of an "Item" that is created directly every time I create an "Item".

How it is:

Item is created via admin, needs "Upvote" and "Downvote" subitems to be created too manually.
How do I change Django to directly create Upvote and Downvote for me?

Thank you!

Comment: But if you want subitems for every item, wouldn't it make sense to simply include the data *in* the item (so some extra columns)? It looks very strange to each time create other items as well. Yes one can use signals, or patch the `.save()` function, but those can be bypassed, and furthermore usually it is better to enforce something *by design*.

Comment: I did that and just added IntegerFields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding and creating subitems each time an Item is created, I just added the "Downvotes" as an IntegerField.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to mention it when you are creating the model.
Suppose you have a Item model like this -

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and then If you want one to one field then the code will be like

```
class SubItem(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It will create subitem when you create Item. To access it you can directly access with dot notation. Suppose you have an SubItem object `sub_item_obj`  then corresponding sub item is `sub_item_obj.item`

Comment: If I understand the question correctly that is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid: to do this work each time theirself.

Comment: " But what I want is a "Subitem" of an "Item" that is created directly every time I create an "Item"- may be I got wrong.

Comment: I think I got it wrong, since it seems the Subitem is created when I create the Item? So I guess my question does not make sense? ^^